# plotting bootstrapped confidence intervals

Tags: r, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I am attempting to plot a bootstrapped linear model and I would like to include the models upper and lower confidence intervals and am not sure I am calculating the bootstrapped upper and lower bounds correctly. Below is an example using the `cars` dataset in `r` in conjunction with the `boot` library.

```
library(boot)


plot(speed~dist,cars,pch=21,bg="grey")
## standard linear model
mod<-lm(speed~dist,cars)
new.dat=seq(0,120,10)
mod.fit<-predict(mod,newdata=data.frame(dist=new.dat),interval="confidence")

lines(new.dat,mod.fit[,1]);#line fit
lines(new.dat,mod.fit[,2],lty=2);#lower confidence interval
lines(new.dat,mod.fit[,3],lty=2);#upper confidence interval

##Bootstrapped Confidence Intervals
lm.boot=function(formula, data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample 
  fit <- lm(formula, data=d)
  return(coef(fit)) 
}

results <- boot(data=cars, statistic=lm.boot, 
                R=100, formula=speed~dist)
N.mod<-nrow(cars)
x.val<-new.dat
y.boot.fit<-(mean(results$t[,2])*x.val)+mean(results$t[,1])
y.boot.fit.uCI<-y.boot.fit+qt(0.975,N.mod-2)*sd(results$t[,2])
y.boot.fit.lCI<-y.boot.fit-qt(0.975,N.mod-2)*sd(results$t[,2])

lines(new.dat,y.boot.fit,col="red")
lines(new.dat,y.boot.fit.lCI,lty=2,col="red");#lower confidence interval
lines(new.dat,y.boot.fit.uCI,lty=2,col="red");#upper confidence interval

legend("bottomright",legend=c("Linear Model","Bootstrapped Model"),lty=1,
col=c("black","red"),ncol=1,cex=1,bty="n",y.intersp=1.5,x.intersp=0.75,
xpd=NA,xjust=0.5)
```

Using this code I get this output where the bootstrapped confidence interval is on top of the bootstrapped fitted line.

[image: linear model examples]

Any help/direction is appreciated. Granted this might be better suited for Cross Validated or other statistic specific boards.

Comment: what is `lm.boot`?

Comment: I don't understand what you think to be the problem.

Comment: @JessicaBurnett I realized I forgot to add `lm.boot`, the question has been updated.

Comment: @42- It seems like the bootstrapped confidence interval is much closer to the fitted line than the confidence interval estimated using the `predict(lm(...))` function. Honestly wanted to double check I am doing it correctly.

Comment: Agree you should be concerned.I think your confusion stems from not returning any information about the moments of the residuals from the function `lm.boot`. This would probably have been better posed as a question on CrossValidated.com since your puzzlement was mainly about statistical concepts and methods. I don't think the error was in your understanding of the R language.